# Horizontal bar plot: distance between bars gets all messed when using multiple \addplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am having a problem I do not understand. I am trying to plot a very simple bar plot using `pgfplots`. When plotting all bars with the same color it does work:

```
\documentclass[border={0.2cm, 0.2cm, 0.2cm, 0.2cm}]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
%\usepackage{figure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{frequency_bar/.style={
    xbar,
    width=.95\textwidth,
    %height=2cm,
    axis y line*= none, axis x line*= bottom,
    xmajorgrids = true,
    xmin=0,xmax=100,
    ytick = {0,1,2,3,4}, 
    yticklabels = {Every year,Every half year,Every month,Every week, Every day},
    yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize, text width=1.2cm, align=center},
    tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
    bar width=5mm, y=10mm,
    xlabel = {Percentage of operators (\%)},
    xlabel style = {font=\small},
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},    
    nodes near coords=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%,
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\scriptsize, color=black},
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[frequency_bar] 
        % 1 gbps
        \addplot[black!80, fill=blue!30!white, mark=none] coordinates {(15,4) (17,3) (46,2) (78,1) (95,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, when I try to color every bar, and split the thing using multiple `\addplot`. The bars get all messed and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
\documentclass[border={0.2cm, 0.2cm, 0.2cm, 0.2cm}]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
%\usepackage{figure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{frequency_bar/.style={
    xbar,
    width=.95\textwidth,
    %height=2cm,
    axis y line*= none, axis x line*= bottom,
    xmajorgrids = true,
    xmin=0,xmax=100,
    ytick = {0,1,2,3,4}, 
    yticklabels = {Every year,Every half year,Every month,Every week, Every day},
    yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize, text width=1.2cm, align=center},
    tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
    bar width=5mm, y=10mm,
    xlabel = {Percentage of operators (\%)},
    xlabel style = {font=\small},
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},    
    nodes near coords=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%,
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\scriptsize, color=black},
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[frequency_bar] 
        \addplot[black!80, fill=blue!30!white, mark=none] coordinates {(95,0)};
        \addplot[black!80, fill=red!30!white, mark=none] coordinates {(78,1)};
        \addplot[black!80, fill=green!30!white, mark=none] coordinates {(46,2)};
        \addplot[black!80, fill=yellow!30!white, mark=none] coordinates {(17,3)};
        \addplot[black!80, fill=purple!30!white, mark=none] coordinates {(15,4)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried playing with the height and `enlarge y limits` but I don't manage to fix it. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE community! See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657390/ can help you.

Comment: Yes, that helped me. Thanks a lot!